# Axios getting error 404 not found (Laravel and React)

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios

Hi everyone while I am trying to display products in database I have problem with fetching data:

```
 app.js:285 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products 404 (Not Found)

dispatchXhrRequest @ app.js:285
xhrAdapter @ app.js:119
dispatchRequest @ app.js:765
Promise.then (async)
request @ app.js:542
Axios.<computed> @ app.js:557
wrap @ app.js:1131
componentDidMount @ app.js:74051
commitLifeCycles @ app.js:59612
commitLayoutEffects @ app.js:62601
callCallback @ app.js:39986
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ app.js:40035
invokeGuardedCallback @ app.js:40090
commitRootImpl @ app.js:62339
unstable_runWithPriority @ app.js:72776
runWithPriority$1 @ app.js:50837
commitRoot @ app.js:62179
finishSyncRender @ app.js:61605
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ app.js:61591
(anonymous) @ app.js:50887
unstable_runWithPriority @ app.js:72776
runWithPriority$1 @ app.js:50837
flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl @ app.js:50882
flushSyncCallbackQueue @ app.js:50870
discreteUpdates$1 @ app.js:61691
discreteUpdates @ app.js:40604
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ app.js:43966
app.js:74056 Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (app.js:699)
    at settle (app.js:960)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (app.js:168)
```

This is my routes/api.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();


Route::resource('products', 'ProductController');

});
```

This my ProductController:

```
<?php


namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;


class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::all();
        return response()->json($products);
    }


    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $product = new Product([
          'title' => $request->get('title'),
          'body' => $request->get('body'),
          'price' => $request->get('price')
        ]);
        $product->save();


        return response()->json('Product Added Successfully.');
    }


    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $product = Product::find($id);
        return response()->json($product);
    }


    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $product = Product::find($id);
        $product->title = $request->get('title');
        $product->body = $request->get('body');
        $product->price = $request->get('price');
        $product->save();


        return response()->json('Product Updated Successfully.');
    }


    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
      $product = Product::find($id);
      $product->delete();


      return response()->json('Product Deleted Successfully.');
    }
}
```

And here is DisplayProdcut.js I am trying to show it in webpage

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import TableRow from './TableRow';
import MyGlobleSetting from './MyGlobleSetting';
class DisplayProduct extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {value: '', products: ''};
     }
     componentDidMount(){
       axios.get('/api/products')
       .then(response => {
         this.setState({ products: response.data });
       })
       .catch(function (error) {
         console.log(error);
       })
     }
     tabRow(){
       if(this.state.products instanceof Array){
         return this.state.products.map(function(object, i){
             return ;

         })
       }
     }


  render(){
    return (


      <div>
        <h1>Your pizza orders</h1>


        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-10"></div>
          <div className="col-md-2">
            <Link to="/add-item">Create Product</Link>
          </div>
        </div><br />


        <table className="table table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Product Title</td>
                <td>Product Body</td>
                <td>Product Price</td>
                <td width="200px">Actions</td>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {this.tabRow()}
            </tbody>
        </table>


              <button className="btn btn-dark"><Link to="display-chosen-products">Add to Cart</Link></button>


    </div>
    )
  }
}
export default DisplayProduct;
```

Here it how it looks on chrome:
[webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WABsc.png)

Please I would appreciate any kind of help, suggestions or ideas.
Thank you so much!

**UPDATE:** TableRow.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import MyGlobleSetting from './MyGlobleSetting';


class TableRow extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let uri = MyGlobleSetting.url + `/api/products/${this.props.obj.id}`;
    axios.delete(uri);
      browserHistory.push('/display-item');
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <tr>
          <td>
            {this.props.obj.id}
          </td>
          <td>
            {this.props.obj.title}
          </td>
          <td>
            {this.props.obj.body}
          </td>
          <td>
            {this.props.obj.price}
          </td>
          <td>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <Link to={"edit/"+this.props.obj.id} className="btn btn-primary">Edit</Link>
           <input type="submit" value="Delete" className="btn btn-danger"/>
         </form>
          </td>
        </tr>
    );
  }
}


export default TableRow;
```

[webpage DisplayProduct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qae5Q.png)

Comment: move the `resource` outside the middleware

Comment: you are help of the God! This solved 404 error. Do you know how to deal with `spread.js:25 POST http://localhost:8000/api/products 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: So after putting resurce outside the middlware 404 error is gone, put products are still not showing on page? I would really appreciate any kind of help, since I am pretty new with this stuff. Thank you so much

Comment: you didn't implement the tabrow function try that ```return this.state.products.map(function(product, i){
              return (
                <tr>
                    <td>{product.id}</td>
                    <td>{product.title}</td>
                </tr>
            )
          })
```

Comment: Yes there it is, but I didnt post it. Please take a look on update in question, and thank you so much I really appreciate it

Comment: put the code of the `tabrow` function in `DisplayProdcut.js` and what is the error you are getting now?

Comment: I would really appreciate if we can discuss about this in discussion chat. I desperately need to solve this. So I have TableRow.js file where is implemented showing items (you can check code in question) on page in Displayproduct I have tabRow function with this code: `tabRow(){
       if(this.state.products instanceof Array){
         return this.state.products.map(function(object, i){
             return ;

         })
       }
     } ` So this code from tabrow is already in DisplayProduct.js

Comment: the tabRow() function doesn't return any thing, you should return the  `TableRow` component like that
 `this.state.products.map(function(object, i){
             return <TableRow obj={object} />;

         }`

Comment: You are right about that. I have added it ,there is no error in webpage displaying items, but products from database are not shown at all you can see updated image in question. Also if I type `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products` I can see all list of products in database. Please do you have any idea how to fix this? and thank you million times This is my mail delila.md@gmail.com please add me I would appreciate this help from you since I am desperate witth this

Comment: check the react dev tools the products state

Comment: It is working now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

you are not returning anything from tabRow ()
in your DisplayProduct.js, modify this:

```js
tabRow(){
  if(this.state.products instanceof Array){
    return this.state.products.map(function(object, i){
      return <TableRow obj={object} key={i} />;
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You could also take care to explain why this works.

Answer (score 0):

Sorrey for the late answer but this may help others.
firstly make sure that you configured the routes on api.php correctly.
then try running this command to clear the routes cache: php artisan route:cache

Answer (score -1):

It's not a middleware problem like sugget ABDEL-RHMAN. If your not auth you don't have a 404 but a 401 error.

Are you sure your laravel app listening on 8000 port ?
How do you launch your app ?

Comment: After putting resource outside the middlware I have error `spread.js:25 POST http://localhost:8000/api/products 500 (Internal Server Error)
spread.js:25 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at e.exports (spread.js:25)
    at e.exports (spread.js:25)
    at XMLHttpRequest.l.onreadystatechange (spread.js:25)`

Comment: I run first server `php artisan serve` and then `npm run dev;`

Comment: After the comand `php artisan serve` I get `http://127.0.0.1:8000
[Fri Apr 24 09:04:14 2020] PHP 7.4.5 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started
[Fri Apr 24 09:04:15 2020] 127.0.0.1:52077 Accepted
[Fri Apr 24 09:04:15 2020] 127.0.0.1:52078 Accepted`